# Как прaвильно: Проведен инструктаж согласно "программы" инструктажа

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика, грамматика

Как правильно написать предложение?

*Проведен инструктаж согласно "программы" инструктажа.*

Answer (score 5):

1) Если вы указываете название  программы: *Проведен инструктаж согласно "Программе инструктажа по охране труда и технике".*

2) Если вы не указываете название  программы: *Проведен инструктаж согласно соответствующей программе.*

Answer (score 0):

Главное, что не *согласно программы*, а ***согласно программе***.

Подробнее - см. у @Vera

В современном языке использование родительного падежа ("согласно чего?") считается стилистически и даже грамматически неправильным, хотя лет двести назад было вполне допустимым и едва ли не предпочтительным. Но сейчас это  махровый "канцелярит".

Comment: Не знаю, на чём основывается Грамота, утверждая так, но она говорит следующее: *Уже в XIX веке конструкция согласно чего, то есть с родительным падежом, расценивалась как характерная примета официально-деловой, канцелярской речи.* Это не поправка, конечно, а просто дополнение. XXI век длинный, и как это менялось, в подробностях вряд ли восстановишь. По крайней мере, это уже вопрос к специалистам в этом. Я воспринимаю без уточнений как целый или практически весь век.

Comment: Везде эта фраза, и нигде нет подробностей.